# Count clicked links, total and unique in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm collecting clicks in a simple table

```
user_id | count | meta
=====================================
  1     |   3   | http://google.com
  1     |   2   | http://twitter.com
  2     |   1   | http://google.com
  3     |   2   | http://example.com
  4     |   1   | http://google.com
```

Now I would like to know

- how many users clicked (at least once - unique)
- how often users clicked any link (total)

output should be

```
uniq | total
=============
 4   |   9
```

currently I have

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT count) AS uniq, SUM(count) AS total FROM my_table
```

but the result is **three** unique users not **four**:

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7988/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count the users:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS uniq, SUM(count) AS total
----------------------^
FROM my_table;
```